# Stuck in the splash screen and won't open

Tags: android-studio

[My android studio stuck in splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYvmY.jpg)

> My android studio stuck in splash screen
>
> These are the errors

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.<clinit>(IdeEventQueue.java:80)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.replaceSystemEventQueue(StartupUtil.java:784)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.patchSystem(StartupUtil.java:768)
at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.executeInitAppInEdt(ApplicationLoader.kt:58)
at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.access$executeInitAppInEdt(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)
at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplication$1$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:363)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field protected java.lang.Runnable java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.runnable accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens java.awt.event" to unnamed module @20302d30
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.InvocationUtil.findRunnableField(InvocationUtil.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.InvocationUtil.(InvocationUtil.java:17)

[I already Tried this method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKm1G.png)

> https://techglimpse.com/google-android-studio-launching-fix-windows/
> and i also tried this method

Comment: Please cut and paste the error here. That makes it easier to Google (for others to find this question).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: yes ive already edit my post im very sorry,

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot of the environment variables, it looks like you took care of JDK_HOME, but you might have forgotten to do JAVA_HOME

Please type

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

If it's not there, point it to the same location listed in your JDK_HOME

Comment: i set up the JAVA_HOME but still it wont open

Comment: @MarclouisLabitoria, Did you restart your computer?

Comment: yes i already tried it,

Answer (score 0):

**I just figure it out** I just download the android studio electric eel and it works again.